# Python Selenium not updating innerHTML

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The following HTML element :

```html
<span class="selectable-text copyable-text" data-lexical-text="true">Hello</span>
```

I would like to change the "Hello" inside the element from Hello to Working.

I tried

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = '\"Working\"';", findElement("div","role","textbox"))
```

with no success.